# How to prevent an included file to generate output in PHP?

Tags: php, include, output

I've got a software that generates outputs using a pattern for several records of data. This file is generated in a specific interval, and due the software is closed source I cant change it.

My Pattern is something like (Without a trailing CR or LF):

```
<? $elem[]='%putValueOfRecordHere%' ?>
```

The output will be:

```
<? $elem[]='1' ?>    
<? $elem[]='2' ?>    
<? $elem[]='3' ?>
```

In fact the software adds a CRLF for each record, including and using this file would add a lot of CRLF to my real used output.

I just want to know, whether there is a built in method, to remove these blank lines, when including a PHP file. Otherwise I will have to parse this file, remove all CRLF, save it without CRLF and include the modified file afterwards, which is pretty much effort.

Comment: That shouldn't cause newline output.

Comment: Yes I know, but it does somehow. The solution is already posted below. (The output file has some thousands of lines, maybe there is somwhere something more than a CRLF)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use output buffering, if the included script isnt actually generating content (like doesnt have echos etc) use below

```
ob_start();
include("myscript.php");
ob_end_clean();
```

if it does generate needed content, the generated content will be in `$content`.

```
ob_start();
include("myscript.php");
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: really helpful.. i WAS getting 1 as output.. now its giving content.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ob_buffers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to fetch the output of the file and send the output to oblivion:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('file');
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```